# Can't turn on NMOS when using 1M pull-down resistor on gate

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, circuit-design, nmos

I am using ATmegA328P MCU to control ignitors which need about 500 mA current to work. To provide such current, I use AO3400A N-MOS to control the ignitors. In early design, I didn't use pull-down resistors. The N-MOS can ignite ignitors when MCU outputs 5V on its gate.

However ignitors maybe ignited unintendly when power on(MCU is reseting during this period of time, IO is unstable). So I put 1M pull-down resistor on the N-MOS's gate which provide 0V when MCU in reset. It successfuly avoid unintended ignition. But I found the N-MOS can't ignite ignitors anymore when MCU outputs HIGH.

My questions is: Why such large resistor makes the N-MOS can't work? According to the datasheet of the MCU, its IO can provide maximum source current of 40 mA. In my view, it's quite large, which means 1M resistor won't reduce IO's drive capability on the N-MOS's gate.

[image]

Comment: Your circuit looks OK, the 1 M resistor should just work. Are you 100% sure your NMOS isn't damaged? Maybe a "flyback diode" is needed across this "ignitor". Are you sure R1 = 100 ohms and R5 = 1 Mohm? Did you double check?

Comment: yes i am sure, I have tried lots of resistors, from 1M to 22M. With the increasing of R value, the success rate of igniton has gradually increased.

Comment: The FET should be pretty much saturated at Vgs=2.5 - have you checked the voltage on the gate pin itself?  It’s hard to believe that such a tiny drop in gate voltage would cause such a problem, but I wonder whether the Arduino is generating an extremely short pulse and the garage capacitance is dominating.  If so, increasing the pulse duration would be the best solution - 1K for R1 seems quite sensible.

Comment: Also Double check the configuration of the IO pin .. set to be an output ? did you wire the correct pin and not accidentally one off ? i know this is stupid, but gotta check everything :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are getting low gate voltage from an incorrect assumption your R value is 1 Meg. e.g. R1, R5 might be in incorrect positions.  You need Vgs > 2V to start conducting __ Amps typically.  The FET seems to be “overkill” for the load current and voltage stated.

Add a flyback diode for any inductive load.

Comment: I am sure I put resistors in their correct positions. I did a series of experiments. I gradually increase the resistance of R5, from 1M to 22M. And I found when R5=10M, the success rate of turing on the mos is 80%. When R5=22M, the success rate reach above 95%.

Comment: Did you measure Vgs? And ensure correct pin polarity? You should expect Vdd on Vgs.  Is reset from EMI?

Comment: I will check Vgs. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: The number of times I have been 'sure' and been proven wrong! Measure, measure measure! 
When something works on paper, but not in reality, there something fundamentally wrong.